# Multiple VPNs - can't activate more than one

Tags: linux, openvpn, iproute2

I have a small problem. In my setup (linux, kernel 3.10.17) I have one ethernet port and multiple WWAN interfaces; each WWAN has its own VPN already activated. The VPNs are connected to the same server through OpenVPN.

Now I have these four VPNs (I chose to use the tun interface, but if in your opinion tap is better I can change). let's call them `tun1`..`tun4`.

Now, I want that all the traffic incoming from the ethernet port go through the VPNs, so I added a table (`ta 55`) and redirected all the traffic incoming from the ethernet to it:

```
ip rule add iif eth0 table 55
```

Now I want to route the traffic to the vpn. Now, if I write

```
ip ro add ta 55 default nexthop dev tun1 weight 256
```

and so the table becomes this:

```
root@mypc:~# ip ro sh ta 55
default dev tun1
```

then everything works. If I change it to another vpn it still works, so the VPNs are working. If, on the other side, I try to enable the routing to all the vpns,  with the command

```
ip ro add ta 55 default scope global nexthop dev tun1 weight 256 nexthop dev tun2 weight 256 nexthop dev tun3 weight 256 nexthop dev tun4 weight 256
```

and so getting the table

```
root@mypc:~# ip ro sh ta 55
default
        nexthop dev tun1 weight 256
        nexthop dev tun2 weight 256
        nexthop dev tun3 weight 256
        nexthop dev tun4 weight 256
```

the ethernet port becomes not able to surf.

What can I do?